How to find application_id, guild_id, channel_id, version, id, and authorization for Discord Bot?

Hello,
I need to make a discord selfbot. i need "application_id, guild_id, channel_id, version, id, and authorization" but I could not find this information in the attached photo. How can i find these variables?
